# SQL Syntax config value Select

Tags: mysql, syntax

I am having some trouble with mysql syntax.  I need to select the `config_value` of 3 entries.

The table is `phpbb3_config`, it has 2 fields

```
config_name | config_value
```

I need the `config_value` from the config_name > num_posts, num_topics, num_users

This is wrong :(

```
SELECT config_value
FROM  `phpbb3_config` 
WHERE config_name =  "num_posts"
AND config_name =  "num_topics"
AND config_name =  "num_users"
```

Comment: You want the logical `OR`, not `AND`, or `config_name IN ('num_posts','num_topics','num_users')`

Comment: How can `config_name` be equal to `num_posts` AND `num_topics` at the same time? :-)  Try using `OR` instead!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`config_name` can't be equal to all 3 of those values. You need to use `IN`:

```
SELECT config_value
FROM  `phpbb3_config` 
WHERE config_name IN ('num_posts', 'num_topics', 'num_users')
```

Comment: Like a charm. Thank you so much Fresh Prince...I tried it 1 hour..pfff all the best for you. this make me happy :)  nice weekend for you

Comment: ah, last question, how can I display it? this doesnt work: SELECT config_value
FROM  `phpbb3_config` 
WHERE config_name IN ('num_posts', 'num_topics', 'num_users')
";
$statshow = mysql_query($statistik) or die("Service temporairly unavailable");
$rowstat = mysql_fetch_array($statshow);
echo $rowstat[num_posts];

Comment: @user2057781 It's out of scope of your original question. Please create a new question. You should also refrain from using `mysql_` functions.